# Useful book(s) on learning Object Oriented Programming in R?

Tags: r, r-s4

I was reading an interesting post on R-bloggers on ''[Object Oriented Programming in R using S4 Classes](http://www.r-bloggers.com/an-example-of-oop-in-gnu-r-using-s4-classes/)". The book "[Statistics and Computing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387989668)" written by Venables and Ripley has some chapters introducing S3 classes and S4 classes in S and R and have been useful to me in terms of understanding the concept of object oriented programming in R.

Do you know of any useful book(s) introducing Object Oriented programming in R in more details with examples like the one in the R blogger?

Comment: Not a useful question but you may want to read Chambers (2008), "Software for Data Analysis", Springer.

Comment: Hi Dirk, Thanks for your answer. I quickly read the chapters of the book. It seems quite the same as Venable's book. What I meant by asking the question above was to find a book specifically for OOP in R (something like Java Prog books in which you could find many detailed explanations/examples on OOP).

Comment: I know of one book being written on this very topic, but it is not yet out. So as I said, Chambers (2008) plus the various web tutorials may be your best bet.

Comment: Would you have any specific web tutorials in mind?

Comment: Your Google skills are probably as good as mine, but for S4 in particular BioC has a number of talks/course: http://www.math.ku.dk/~richard/courses/bioconductor2009/handout/17_08_Monday/OOP-handouts.pdf

Comment: What a great website. I appreciate it Dirk.

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters said, "Software for Data Analysis" by John chambers is excellent. I would also recommend the R manual "Writing R Extensions", although it can get quite technical. For more introductory sources, I would look into these documents: [How Methods Work](http://developer.r-project.org/howMethodsWork.pdf) by John Chambers, [this S4 tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Genolini-S4tutorialV0-5en.pdf) by Christophe Genolini, and [this useful powerpoint](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/biostat776/classes-methods.pdf), which is a nice high-level overview.